# Ads will not auto refresh in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I uploaded apps in Windows Phone 8, and added AdControl which uses Microsoft Pubcenter advertisement.

Even if I mark the IsAutoRefreshEnabled property to True for my AdControl, advertise in that control does not auto refresh. Do I need to set any other properties or events?

Code I have used till now:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
    <my:AdControl
        Height="80"
        Name="adControl1"
        Width="480"
        IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True"
        AdUnitId="test_client" //Live AdUnit ID is provided
        ApplicationId="Image480_80" //Live Application ID is provided
      />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code what you did so far.?

Comment: for how much time did you wait for new ad ? for PubCenter I believe is 60 seconds by default to rotate to a new ad.

Comment: I kept app open for more than 15-2 mins. but ads were not refreshed automatically.

Comment: Fill rates are as low as 18-20% for pubcenter. So if the AdControl is unable to fetch a new ad then the previous one is displayed. Also if you are idle for too long then no more ads are requested. Relish the fact that ads are showing!

Comment: Then which ad provider is more suitable to earn more through my app?